# Нужна ли запятая перед словами "на что" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Минпромторг ищет на что поднять таможенные пошлины.* Нужна ли запятая перед "на что"? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Минпромторг ищет, на что поднять таможенные пошлины.**

**Это СПП  с придаточным изъяснительным**, в роли союзного слова падежная форма местоимения, поэтому запятая ставится.

Если это заголовок, то **можно предположить, что запятую не поставили именно в заголовке.** Но по правилам запятые в заголовках ставятся на общих основаниях, а вот точка не ставится.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168

В конце заголовков **точка не ставится**, независимо от их структуры (односоставное номинативное предложение, двусоставное и т. д.):

**Запятая в заголовках ставится на общих основаниях** (т. е. в случаях, предусмотренных правилами ее постановки): Город, в котором мы живём; Подделка, которая не карается законом; Там, где создаётся настроение; Страна, идущая вперёд; Вот он какой, этот подводный мир.

Answer (score 2):

Вот [здесь](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8D%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/article/46373-minpromtorg-ishchet-na-chto-podnyat-tamozhennye-poshliny.html) этот заголовок статьи опубликован без запятой.

> Экономика
>   Минпромторг ищет на что поднять таможенные пошлины
>   Анастасия Гладких / 20.02.2018

Однако я думаю, это ошибка. Это СПП, и придаточное должно отделяться запятой.

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> И всё с большей ясностью толпа чувствует свое одиночество, ощущает какой-то обман и, всё более раздражаясь, зорко ищет, на что бы положить свою руку. [Максим Горький. Заграничные впечатления (1906)]